# JOLT Transformation Needed for removing the element from array of JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying  remove a field from array of JSON using JOLT Transformation. below is the input JSON and expected output JSON.
can you suggest the JOLT  transformation for the mentioned scenario

**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "Actual": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "storeId": "newton_stores",
        "bulkDiscountDisplayedEvents": null
      },
      "Field_to_Delete": "Y"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "finalReceipt": {
          "totalAmount": "708.5",
          "totalDiscount": "67.9",
          "multiOfferEvents": [],
          "bulkDiscountDisplayedEvents": []
        }
      },
      "Field_to_Delete": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

**expected Output**

```json
{
  "Actual": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "storeId": "newton_stores",
        "bulkDiscountDisplayedEvents": null
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "finalReceipt": {
          "totalAmount": "708.5",
          "totalDiscount": "67.9",
          "multiOfferEvents": [],
          "bulkDiscountDisplayedEvents": []
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove spec while looping through the sub-elements of the **Actual** array such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Actual": {
        "*": {
          "Field_to_Delete": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `*` wilcard represents the indexes of the array.